# ために vs こと when saying thank you

Tags: grammar, word-choice

When saying I'm thankful for something which one is better, or can I use both? こと or ために?

> お弁当**こと**ありがとうございました。
>
> お弁当の**ために**ありがとうございました。

Also, when using こと do I need to use の?(I mean in this example and not as a nominalizer)

And when using ために do I always need a particle to connect or its ok to say something like:

> 名古屋は生きるために良い街ですね！

PS. When using it on smartphone browser it won't hint the tags for me, that's why I'm going with the generic grammar tag, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

お弁当ことありがとうございました and お弁当のためにありがとうございました are unnatural. You can say お弁当(を)ありがとうございました. You can omit を.

名古屋は生きるために良い街ですね is also unnatural. 名古屋は生きる**には**良い街ですね is more natural but I feel this is still unnatural. 名古屋は**住むには**良い街ですね (Nagoya is a good city to live in.) would be natural.

I think when using こと and ために, when they attach to a noun, の is necessary, as in:

> あなた**の**こと
>   学校**の**こと
>   あなた**の**ために
>   家族**の**ために

When they attach to a verb, の isn't necessary, as in:

> 走ること
>   笑うこと
>   生きるために
>   勉強するために